# Draper::UninferrableDecoratorError (Could not infer a decorator)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, decorator, draper

I want to infer a decorator in a controller, so I generate a decorator the  normal way (rails g decorator) and infer it in the controller. However, when I test with Postman, I get the error:

`Could not infer a decorator for Employers::Job`.

The error message shows that my syntax in the controller is incorrect (where `.decorate` is used), I don't know where I am going wrong.

I have tried changing the way of writing and specifying the decorator explicitly ( `@job = Employers::JobDecorator.find(params[:id]).decorate`), but again this gives a NoMethodError (undefined method `find' for Employers::JobDecorator:Class).

This is part of the controller:

```
  def show
    @job = @employer.jobs.find(params[:id])
    render json: @job
  end
end
```

This is the decorator at the beginning:

```
  def attributes
    #somethings
  end
```

**UPDATE 2**
Thanks to the suggestion in the comments, things changed after I used `Employers::JobDecorator.decorate(@job)` in the controller, but I got a new error. The message says `undefined method 'attributes' for nil:NilClass`, the source is a line of code from the following file:

#app/decorators/employer/job_decorator.rb

```
  def attributes
    super.merge(
      {
        id: nil, 
        emp: nil, 
      }).delete_if { |k, v| 
          ['class_name'].include?(k)
        }
  end
```

What is the reason for this?

**UPDATE 3**

Following the advice of the comments, I got back to the previous error after changing some of the decorators to the following.

```
  def attrs
    model.attributes.merge(
      {
```

The error is "NoMethodError in Employers::JobController#show", and the file pointed to is one of the lines in "config/initializer/active_model/serialization.rb" (last line extracted below):

```
module ActiveModel
   module Serialization
     def serializable_hash(options = nil)
       options ||= {}

       attribute_names = attributes.keys
```

**UPDATE 4**

If I change the way decorator is written, the result is still similar to "undefined method `id' for #Employers::JobDecorator:0x00007ff3cdd3f748"

```
class Employers::JobDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  delegate_all

  def attributes
    {
      id:           nil,
      name:         nil,
      slug:         nil
    }
  end

end
```

**UPDATE 5**

I suspect the reason is that @job is nil, so I added something to the controller, finally solved the problem. I got it in the wrong direction.

Comment: try with `Api::V2::Employers::JobDecorator.decorate(@job)`

Comment: @razvans thank you! I updated the problem description, hope you are interested in taking a look

Comment: I got another NoMethodError: ```undefined method `attributes' for nil:NilClass```

Comment: What line exactly? What happens if you say `def attrs` instead of `def attributes` and replace `super` with `model.attributes` ?

Comment: I updated the problem description (UPDATE 3), It goes back to the previous porblem (undefined method `attributes'). I doubt, is this related to a certain model or table?

Comment: Why do you need that initializer? What's so special about it? If you remove it, everything should be alright.

Comment: I don't think that's necessarily related. I edited "UPDATE 4", hope that is a clue.

Comment: If I delete serialization.rb, I also get the same error "undefined method `attributes' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: Such a weird issue. Is @job nil?

Comment: I want to test it with ````defined?(@job)``` but I can't find a way to execute it

Comment: Just do a "raise @job.inspect"

Comment: I insert "raise @job.inspect" on the line before render json and it shows:```#<Api::V2::Employers::JobDecorator:0x00007fa968d30d60 @object=nil, @context={}>```

Comment: Is object is nil it means @job is nil, or the object you try to decorate is nil.

Comment: I did some things in UPDATE 5, but it still doesn't work, is there any snake that can be improved?

Comment: Framework challenge - why are you using a decorator for an API? Draper is really used to clean up your view logic by wraping model methods. In an JSON API you would use a serializer instead to handle JSON generation instead. https://thoughtbot.com/blog/better-serialization-less-as-json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draper `infers` the decorator from the object that is decorated and in your scenario is `Employers::Job`.

Because the decorator you want to be used has a totally different name, `Api::V2::Employers::JobDecorator`, you need to explicitly specify it.

So, `Api::V2::Employers::JobDecorator.decorate(@job)` is what you need.

More information, [here](https://github.com/drapergem/draper#decorating-objects)